# I can't seem to install the 'ecospat' package on R studio for windows

Tags: r, windows, installation

I am unable to install the 'ecospat' package on R and I was wondering why this could be?

After running the following bit of code using R in windows.....

```
install.packages('ecospat')
```

This is the error message I get...

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/etelford.IC.000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependencies ‘pROC’, ‘biomod2’
>
> There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
>            binary source needs_compilation
>   pROC     1.14.0 1.16.2              TRUE
>   biomod2 3.3-7.1  3.4.6             FALSE
>   ecospat     3.0    3.1             FALSE
>
> Binaries will be installed
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/pROC_1.14.0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 941305 bytes (919 KB)
>   downloaded 919 KB
>
> package ‘pROC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       C:\Users\etelford.IC.000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsBJC01\downloaded_packages
>   installing the source packages ‘biomod2’, ‘ecospat’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/biomod2_3.4.6.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 665227 bytes (649 KB)
>   downloaded 649 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ecospat_3.1.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2179055 bytes (2.1 MB)
>   downloaded 2.1 MB
>
> - installing *source* package 'biomod2' ...
>     ** package 'biomod2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading
>     Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     namespace 'pROC' 1.14.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.15.0 is required
>     ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'biomod2'
> - removing 'C:/Users/etelford.IC.000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/biomod2'
>     In R CMD INSTALL
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\etelford.IC.000\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\ETELFO~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsBJC01/downloaded_packages/biomod2_3.4.6.tar.gz' had status 1
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘biomod2’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency 'biomod2' is not available for package 'ecospat'
> - removing 'C:/Users/etelford.IC.000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ecospat'
>     In R CMD INSTALL
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\etelford.IC.000\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\ETELFO~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsBJC01/downloaded_packages/ecospat_3.1.tar.gz' had status 1
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘ecospat’ had non-zero exit status

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

thanks

Comment: The text after the first bullet point will probably lead you in the right direction. ecospat requires pROC >= 1.15.0. Try `install.packages("pROC")` first and then `packageVersion("pROC")`. It might be the case that you have to install pROC from source. If you can't yet install from source, search online for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to update your R version. I think you use an R 3.4 version. 
The main reason why your installation fails is that you need to install `pROC > 1.15` and this is not available for R 3.4.